# how to repack jar after `jav xvf`?

Tags: java, maven, jar

I use

```
jar xvf my.jar
```

to unpack it, and I get

```
 BOOT-INF  META-INF   org
```

META-INF has three parts:

```
MANIFEST.MF  maven  spring-configuration-metadata.json
```

and I modifed an application.properties within org, and then I want to repack it into my.jar.

I used:

```
jar cvfm my.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF BOOT-INF/ org
```

but `maven  spring-configuration-metadata.json` are not packed into my.jar, so how to repack my.jar?

Comment: You need to add `META-INF/maven` and `META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json` to the command line, anywhere after the target .jar file name. Or you could just use `uvfm` instead of `cvfm`: that will just update the existing .jar file.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your goal is to update only the content of `META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json` you don't need to extract the whole archive.

assuming your `app.jar` looks like this

```
jar tvf app.jar
     0 Tue Sep 05 07:54:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/
    68 Tue Sep 05 07:54:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Tue Sep 05 07:54:02 CEST 2017 org/
     0 Tue Sep 05 07:54:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/
     3 Tue Sep 05 07:54:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json
     0 Tue Sep 05 07:54:02 CEST 2017 BOOT-INF/
```

extract `META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json` only

```
jar xf app.jar META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json
```

Which extracts the file in the current directory in the subdirectory `META-INF`.

update the file

```
echo bar >> META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json
```

update the `app.jar`

```
jar uf app.jar META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json
```

check the `app.jar`

```
jar tvf app.jar
     0 Tue Sep 05 07:54:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/
    68 Tue Sep 05 07:54:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF
     0 Tue Sep 05 07:54:02 CEST 2017 org/
     0 Tue Sep 05 07:54:02 CEST 2017 META-INF/maven/
     8 Tue Sep 05 07:54:16 CEST 2017 META-INF/spring-configuration-metadata.json
     0 Tue Sep 05 07:54:02 CEST 2017 BOOT-INF/
```

Answer (score 0):

Since you are using options: -f, -m the "my.jar" is the name for -f and META-INF/MANIFEST.MF is the name for -m, and so "BOOT-INF/ org" are the files to pack (i.e. META-INF was not specified).
Try: `jar cvfm my.jar META-INF/MANIFEST.MF BOOT-INF META-INF org`